# Django recuperar un objeto de un modelo

Tags: django, djangorestframework

A Partir de un registro  recorrer 60 registros a tras respecto el id y recuperar "xcampo"  para sacar medidas como media y desviación.

Este proceso lo hago actualmente en el front con vue.js, haciendo 60 gets a la api partiendo del id, y si existe el registro hago un increment hasta obtener mis 60 datos. Pero esto es lento.

```
async fetchGraph() {
    headurl = this.urlParam
    idTemp = this.curveId
    arrayLotes = []
    while (arrayLotes.length<60 && idTemp>0) {
      const r = await this.fetch(headurl+`?lote=`+idTemp, {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      }).then(async(r) => {
        // status 404 or 500 will set ok to false
        if (r.ok) {
          // Success: convert data received & run callback
          const data = await aHandleFetchResp(r)
          if (data[0].recobro > 0)
          arrayLotes.push(data[0])
        }
      }).catch(e => console.error('EXCEPTION: ', e))
      idTemp -= 1
    }
    return {...arrayLotes}
  }
```

Comment: Es necesario que compartas tu código completo para así poder ayudarte, esto incluye urls, view, forms, templates, js, etc.

Comment: solo ocupo saber algun metodo para hacer que mi api devuelva un json con la consulta siguiente.
`select hal.fecha, hal.id, db.media_dbl_dqo, had.seleccionado_baja
    from controldbo db
inner join detalledbo had on db.lote_id = had.id
inner join lotedbo hal on db.lote_id = hal.id
 where db.seleccionado=2
order by 2 desc
    limit 60 ;`